# Setting frame continuation number (autobreakcount)

Tags: beamer, counters, allowframebreaks

I want to set the value of `\beamer@autobreakcount` manually.

I have a frame divided into several slides with `allowframebreaks`. Then I should have a frame with another title, after which I want to have slides with the previous title and the slides numeration continued.

I mean:

```
Slide A (1)
Slide A (2)
Slide A (3)
Slide B
Slide A (4)
etc...
```

Is there any way to acheve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote the beamer user guide about the `allowframebreaks` option:

> The use of this option is evil.

Instead you can use overlays to split your frame into multiple slides. This ways you can easily insert another frame in between with the help of the `\againframe` macro:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\slideinframe}{\number\beamer@slideinframe} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}<1>[label=foo]
    \frametitle{Slide A (\slideinframe)}
  \begin{onlyenv}<1>
  content for 1. slide
  \end{onlyenv}
  \begin{onlyenv}<2>
  content for 2. slide
  \end{onlyenv}    
\end{frame} 
    
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide B}
Content for slide B
\end{frame}  

\againframe<2->{foo}
  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Exacly what I needed!

Comment: @VadimZyamalov You're welcome!